# Is it possible to create a custom product view page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am new in magento, I need to have two product view pages in magento.
One for local products and another for international products. I have customized the default product view page in order to display local products.
International product  view page will be displayed, when I clicked on 'international product' link, which I had provided in the default product view page. I have created a fully functional module with name 'international' for international product.  But now  I am in utter confusion.

How can I make my custom module exactly function like the default product view page? Is it the proper way to make another product view page?

Please suggest.

Comment: learn overriding of phtmls.then you could do it easily.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Mahmood Rehman. Can you suggest me some reference pages?

Comment: i think it will be better to use same view page for both operation.while in start of the page set some variable and display data against that.

Comment: you mean i need to load the international products when the 'international product' link is clicked in the same page . isn't it?

Comment: yes but do this action on some sort of variable value like session or block_id.I didn't do like that before but i hope it works.

Comment: thanks. i definitely do a try. and will inform you the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways.

1. In Manage Product on Edit page of a product you can define custom layout in Design Tab.
   But then you have to do same thing for all the products you want to have new design and in future it will be hard to manage which product using what layout.
2. Provide an dropdown attribute for product lets say locality_type with options "International","Local" and then change layout dynamically as per attribute value with the help of layout handler.

I find second way much handy as I can identify that on the basis of attribute value my layout is being changed and changing this attribute value will change my layout easily.

This is how it will implemented.

update `initProductLayout` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php`

After `$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_' . $product->getId());` place these line

```
if($product->getAttributeText('locality_type')=='International')
    $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_INTERNATIONAL');
if($product->getAttributeText('locality_type')=='Local')
    $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_LOCAL');
```

Now Update `{theme}/layout/catalog.xml`. After `</PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>` place these lines

```
<PRODUCT_INTERNATIONAL>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view_international.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_INTERNATIONAL>
<PRODUCT_LOCAL>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view_local.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_LOCAL>
```

Now only thing remaining is that you have to create these two files `view_local.phtml` and `view_internationl.phtml` in `{theme}/template/catalog/product`

You can place different code in view files to make them look different. and For further changes you have your own handler tag in `catalog.xml`. Use it as you want.

Comment: thank you so much. this seems to be a good solution for my problem.\